# Deriving the formula for Lie bracket from taking the derivative of the Adjoint map

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

following Page 107, Fulton/Harris First course in Rep theory:

Let G be a Lie group and $\gamma: I \rightarrow G$ be an arc with $\gamma(0)=e$ and $\gamma'(0)=X$

$[X,Y]=ad(X)(Y) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(Ad(\gamma(t))(Y))$

Applying the product rule to $Ad(\gamma(t))(Y) = \gamma(t)Y\gamma(t)^{-1}$

This is:

$$=\gamma'(0) \cdot Y \cdot \gamma(0) + \gamma(0) \cdot Y \cdot (-\gamma(0)^{-1} \cdot \gamma'(0) \cdot \gamma(0)^{-1}) = X \cdot Y - Y \cdot X$$

---

I'm confused about the above application of the product rule... The first summand makes sense, but then in the second summand, to the right of the $Y$, why is there more than just $\gamma'(0)$? We have $-\gamma(0)^{-1}$ and $\gamma(0)^{-1}$.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it helps but i'm still confused. $\gamma(t)$ is not a vector (so not a matrix), but it's derivative is (so is a column matrix).... and your link tells how to take the derivative in general of any matrix. Okay I think I see it. taking the derivative of an inverse matrix is quite different than say, applying the chain rule to $x^{-1}$

Comment: In your link, why is it the chain rule that gives the implication? It looks like the product rule to me

Comment: Yes that's definitely product rule.

Comment: Notice that the authors *define* $[X,Y]:=ad(X)(Y)$ in the general setting. Here they are showing this agrees with the matrix commutator definition in the specific case of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, so $\gamma(t)$ *is* a matrix.